# Placing table of contents not immediately after title page

Tags: asciidoc, asciidoctor

Using **asciidoc**, I'd like to place a the table of contents on the third page. At best, I can only manage to place it on page 2; after the title page.

My expectation is that something like this should work:

```
= My book
A book to enjoy

== Preface
Enjoy my book

== Table of contents
:toc:

== Chapter One
It was the best of times ...
```

... but the table of contents still ends up on page 2.

Is it possible to choose where to place the Table of Contents?

**EDIT:**

The reason I want the TOC on a different page is because I am copying a template which has a section before the table of contents.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's possible, **but not supported in all backends**.

Setting `:toc: macro` lets you use the `toc::[]` macro anywhere in the document.

Since in your example you seem to want a custom TOC title, I used `:toc-title:` to get rid of the default TOC title.

```
:toc: macro
:toc-title:
= My book
A book to enjoy

== Preface
Enjoy my book

== Table of contents
toc::[]

== Chapter One
It was the best of times ...
```

For more information see:

- https://asciidoctor.org/docs/user-manual/#manual-placement
- https://asciidoctor.org/docs/user-manual/#table-of-contents-summary

You can test the code here: https://asciidoclive.com/

Comment: Thanks. Was away so took a while to test it out.

Comment: Asciidoctor-PDF doesn't support it yet, but there's an open issue: https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor-pdf/issues/1030

Answer (score 1):

http://www.methods.co.nz/asciidoc/userguide.html#_page_breaks

> A line of three or more less-than (<<<) characters will generate a hard page break in DocBook and printed HTML outputs

This should at least get you on the right page. No pun intended.

Comment: Thanks. Especially for the unintended pun ;). I think I should have been more clear in explaining why I want this. I'm copying an existing document written in word where the 'preface' section comes before the table of contents. Therefore, I can't have a blank page before either.

Comment: Shoot. Unfortunately that's out of my know-how :\